# Create FCE with FLUX in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I followed the [instruction](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/content-element.html) on FluidTYPO3, and get my FCE template done like below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="Grid"/>

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="twoColumns" options="{group: 'Grid Elements'}">
        <flux:field.input name="settings.left.class" default="col-sm-6" required="true"/>
        <flux:field.input name="settings.right.class" default="col-sm-6" required="true"/>
    </flux:form>
    <flux:grid>
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column name="left"/>
            <flux:grid.column name="right"/>
        </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
    <div class="{settings.left.class}">
        <flux:content.render area="left"/>
    </div>
    <div class="{settings.right.class}">
        <flux:content.render area="right"/>
    </div>
</f:section>
</html>
```

And it works in my BE even without the `Preview`, `TYPO3 v8.7.4` and `flux v8.2.1`. However, when I visit the FE, it shows `ERROR: Content Element with uid "31" and type "flux_2columns" has no rendering definition!`. Does it mean that I still need some TS to get the FCE working for FE? If so, what should it be like?

Comment: Did you install **EXT:fluidcontent**?

Comment: No. According to the github, it's said fluidcontent is obsolete, and flux would take over everything, but seems that's not correct, I have to take more steps.

Comment: Doesn't GitHub say **EXT:fluidcontent_core** is obsolete?

Comment: Yes, that's why I only use the latest flux from TER. Do you have any idea how to get the FCE working correct?

Comment: You are right, **EXT:fluidcontent** is also obsolete know - I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it working, but need 2 more steps.

Register `flux` as a content plugin.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'FluidTYPO3.Flux',
    'Content',
    [
        'Content' => 'render, error',
    ]
);
```

Add the TS for the new CTYPE

```
tt_content.flux_2columns = USER
tt_content.flux_2columns {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = FluidTYPO3
    extensionName = Flux
    pluginName = Content
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the correct solution I think. According to https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1442, all you need is to change `includeStaticTypoScriptSourcesAtEnd` to `includeStaticTypoScriptSources` in `EXT:flux/ext_localconf.php`, no more steps. Keep everything the same as how you did with `fluidcontent`.